# Read in PGM file into 2D array C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, ascii, pgm

I am trying to read in a `P2 PGM` image into a 2D array in C.

The array is 5 rows and 7 columns. When i try to read in the values from the `.PGM` file all i get are 0s. When i create my own .txt file with 
the same 5 rows and 7 columns as the image it works perfectly. So i think the problem is the P2 header.

```
int main() {

int aarray [5] [7] = {0};
int cols = 7;
int rows = 5;
int i;
int j;

FILE *input_fptr;

input_fptr = fopen("image1.pgm", "r");

if (input_fptr!=NULL)
{
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            fscanf(input_fptr, "%d", &aarray[i][j]);
            printf("%d\n", aarray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
fclose(input_fptr);
return 0;
}
```

Is there a way of skipping these first 3 lines then reading in the values into the array?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read and discard however many number of lines you don't want to process.

Comment: Read characters from file until 3 newlines are encountered? What have you tried?

Comment: i have seen other solutions to similar problems that involved strings and characters, that has me confused as i thought this would only involve integers?

Comment: the P2 header can indeed have strings, and even comments